# How to access third party extension sales_order column via Order API in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

We're using Novuna PaybyFinance (formerly Hitachi PaybyFinance) version 1.7.1 in Magento 2.4.3-p3 and need to be able to access Novuna's column **`'finance_application_no'`** which is present in the **`sales_order`** column via the Order API.

Can anyone guide me on how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to Mohit Patel for his advice and setting me off in the right direction. I ended up getting it to work like this:

registration.php

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
     \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
     'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

etc/extension_attributes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface">
        <attribute code="finance_application_no" type="string" />
        <attribute code="finance_deposit" type="int" />
        <attribute code="finance_amount" type="int" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0"></module>
</config>
```

webapi_rest/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="orderInformationUpdate" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Api\OrderRepository" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Plugin/Api/OrderRepository.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\api;

use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderExtensionFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderSearchResultInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;


class OrderRepository
{

    const FINANCE_DEPOSIT = 'finance_deposit';
    const FINANCE_AMOUNT = 'finance_amount';
    const FINANCE_APPLICATION_NO = 'finance_application_no';
    

    /**
     * Order Extension Attributes Factory
     *
     * @var OrderExtensionFactory
     */
    protected $extensionFactory;

    /**
     * OrderRepositoryPlugin constructor
     *
     * @param OrderExtensionFactory $extensionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(OrderExtensionFactory $extensionFactory)
    {
        $this->extensionFactory = $extensionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Add "finance_deposit", "finance_amount" and "finance_application_no" extension attributes to order data object to make them accessible in API data
     *
     * @param OrderRepositoryInterface $subject
     * @param OrderInterface $order
     *
     * @return OrderInterface
     */
    public function afterGet(OrderRepositoryInterface $subject, OrderInterface $order)
    {
        $financeDeposit = $order->getData(self::FINANCE_DEPOSIT);
        $financeAmount = $order->getData(self::FINANCE_AMOUNT);
        $financeApplicationNo = $order->getData(self::FINANCE_APPLICATION_NO);
        $extensionAttributes = $order->getExtensionAttributes();
        $extensionAttributes = $extensionAttributes ? $extensionAttributes : $this->extensionFactory->create();
        $extensionAttributes->setFinanceDeposit($financeDeposit);
        $extensionAttributes->setFinanceAmount($financeAmount);
        $extensionAttributes->setFinanceApplicationNo($financeApplicationNo);
        $order->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);

        return $order;
    }

    /**
     * Add "finance_deposit", "finance_amount" and "finance_application_no" extension attributes to order data object to make them accessible in API data
     *
     * @param OrderRepositoryInterface $subject
     * @param OrderSearchResultInterface $searchResult
     *
     * @return OrderSearchResultInterface
     */
    public function afterGetList(OrderRepositoryInterface $subject, OrderSearchResultInterface $searchResult)
    {
        $orders = $searchResult->getItems();

        foreach ($orders as &$order) {
            $financeDeposit = $order->getData(self::FINANCE_DEPOSIT);
            $financeAmount = $order->getData(self::FINANCE_AMOUNT);
            $financeApplicationNo = $order->getData(self::FINANCE_APPLICATION_NO);
            $extensionAttributes = $order->getExtensionAttributes();
            $extensionAttributes = $extensionAttributes ? $extensionAttributes : $this->extensionFactory->create();
            $extensionAttributes->setFinanceDeposit($financeDeposit);
            $extensionAttributes->setFinanceAmount($financeAmount);
            $extensionAttributes->setFinanceApplicationNo($financeApplicationNo);
            $order->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);
        }

        return $searchResult;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not clear your question but as per my understanding I have added below code and please check.

1. First, you need to create a custom module with the extension's
   **`sales_order`** column.
2. In the module's **`di.xml`** file, you need to add the following code to
   define the **`sales_order`** column as an extension attribute:

Here is the code:-

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface">
        <attribute code="finance_application_no" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

3. Next, you need to create a plugin that will add the **`sales_order`**
   column to the Order API. In the module's **`etc/webapi.xml`** file, you
   need to add the following code:

Here is the code:-

```
<route url="/V1/orders/:id" method="GET">
    <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface" method="get"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous"/>
    </resources>
    <data>
        <parameter name="id" force="true">%id</parameter>
    </data>
</route>
```

4. Finally, you can access the sales_order column via the Order API by
   calling the following endpoint:

Here is the URL:-

```
GET /V1/orders/:id
```

Where **`:id`** is the order ID you want to retrieve.

Let me know if any query.

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your reply. I have followed the steps but get "Invalid Document 
Element 'extension_attributes': This element is not expected.
Line: 3" re. di.xml

Comment: Please share your full code.